# IP, and page-specific redirect?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to send a particular IP, that is trying to get one page on my site, to another page, and do this through my .htaccess file. I've seen many general descriptions of how to do it (in many syntactically different ways) but frankly none of them work. I put these command
s, of the sort

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^99\.888\.777\.66$
RewriteRule ^/askedforpage\.html /redirecttopage.html [R,NE,NC]
```

in my *.htaccess* file ... but these commands simply leave my site non-functional. I'm using Apache 2.2, on a Mac with OS 10.6.8.

How do I do this??

---

Here is my .htaccess file, without the "deny" commands for malicious IPs.

```
Header set Accept-Ranges none   
order allow,deny     
allow from all   
Redirect permanent xyz.html http://xxyyzz.com/header.htm
```

Comment: "leave my site non-functional"? Those commands shouldn't actually do anything in a per-directory .htaccess file, since `^/askedforpage\.html` (with a slash prefix) will never match - do you have anything else in your htaccess file? Also, "I'm trying to **send** a particular IP" - presumably you don't mean "send"? You are wanting to redirect based on the IP address?

Comment: Yes, I have a number of IP-denials there (Chinese, mostly), and they work fine. Also a Range restriction. As to leaving my site non-functional, I notice that's what errors in an .htaccess do in general. Yes "send". When an IP asked for "askedforpage.html", I want to SEND them to "redirecttopage.html". I only want to do that for one IP, so yes, this is based on the IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really very much wrong with the code you have posted. There are certainly no errors in your code that should leave your site non-functional. As it stands it is syntactically valid. However, check your line endings to make sure you have no spurious characters - this can cause problems.

Try the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^99\.888\.777\.66$
RewriteRule ^askedforpage\.html /redirecttopage.html [R,NC,L]
```

I have removed the `/` (slash) prefix in the `RewriteRule` pattern. The directory prefix is removed in per-directory .htaccess files before the pattern is matched (so URL patterns never start with a slash). I have also removed the `NE` flag - this is unnecessary in the code you have posted (although is not an error).

**EDIT:** I've added the `L` (LAST) flag, although to be honest it shouldn't make much of  a difference in this case, providing there are no conflicting rules in your (or another) .htaccess file - which there don't appear to be from your question.

It is admittedly more usual to specify the `L` flag in `RewriteRule` external redirects since generally you do not want the rewrite engine to reprocess your rules after you have established the redirect.

Comment: Well, I coped *precisely* what you suggested in your code block into my .htaccess file, and I checked all line endings to make sure there were no spurious characters. As a result, I can't get anything off my server. I get a "Forbidden   You don't have permissions to access ... on this server" message for everything I try to access.

Comment: ... I got cut off ... This was after I made some dummy "askedforpage.html" and "redirecttopage.html" files. I get that error for several differerent browsers. As soon as I remove those lines from my .htaccess file, everything is fine again. I think I need some diagnostics. I'm stumped.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? (But even if it isn't, those directives should simply be ignored.) At the moment I can only assume it is conflicting with other directives in your htaccess file, since that code by itself should not cause any problems. The only possible error, that I can see, would be a 404 if "redirecttopage.html" did not exist. Could you paste your .htaccess in its entirety into your question so we can take a look?

Comment: OK, here is my .htaccess file (minus the "deny" commands to dispense with malicious IPs). My apologies, but I don't know how to create a list. I put in two spaces after a line, but that doesn't add a line break. The formatting in this comments section is kinda weird. I've put a # sign before each command.     #Header set Accept-Ranges none  
#order allow,deny   
#allow from all   #Redirect permanent xyz.html http://xxyyzz.com/header.htm

Comment: This is a puzzle. Can you confirm that `mod_rewrite` is enabled on your server? I have tried the above code, with the additional code you have added to your question, and it works OK for me on my test server. I have also added the `L` flag to the end of the `RewriteRule`, but I don't think this will make much of a difference here (since there's only one directive). Try removing everything apart from the mod_rewrite code - does that still not work? Is `FollowSymLinks` enabled? (I've updated my answer to include this in the example.)

Comment: Also, what error is being generated exactly? You might need to check your error logs.

Comment: Success! The first thing I tried was adding the "L", as you did. It worked! Everything else stayed the same. Now, my server doesn't give me errors when I ask for stuff, *and* when the designated IP (and only that IP) tries to get askedforpage.html, they get redirecttopage.html instead. Many thanks, not only for the critical information, but for your patience in dealing with me!

Comment: @user618 if you feel your question is answered, please mark it as such and consider any appropriate votes.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to report that the advice of w3d was exactly right. The way you do this is

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^99\.888\.777\.66$    
RewriteRule ^askedforpage\.html /redirecttopage.html [R,NC,L]
```

(I already had FollowSymLinks on, and `mod_rewrite` enabled.) The "L" (LAST) flag is important!

These *.htaccess* commands look for a request by IP `99.888.777.66` (and only that IP) for the page "`askedforpage.html`", and return the page "`redirecttopage.html`" instead. Unless otherwise denied, that IP can get anything else.

Tip 'o the bowler to w3d.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it working OK. However, on the Stack Exchange network it is preferable to mark the (other) answer as "accepted" - if this is what helped you - by clicking on the _tick_ to the left of the answer, rather than answering your own question with what is essentially a _comment_ (which is likely to get deleted by moderators). By _accepting_ an answer, it takes the question out of the unanswered question queue, informing other users. (However, you need 15+ rep points before you can upvote an answer, so answer or ask another question! Welcome to Webmasters. :)